# Flutter generic function callback

Tags: flutter, dart, generics, lambda, callback

can you comment?

```dart
typedef ButtonChangedCallback = void Function<T>(T value);

class MyWidget<T> extends StatefulWidget {
  ButtonChangedCallback? onCallback;
  const MyWidget(
      {required Key key,
      this.onCallback})
      : super(key: key);
```

I would like to create such template widget to be used with different enums. So it can signal what value from the enum was selected.
But I am unable to find how to later assign to the "onCallback" method.

```dart
MyWidget(
        key: const Key("RadioControls"),
        onCallback: <MyEnum>(MyEnum value) =>
          setState(() {
            someSettings.value = value;
          }),
      )
```

This does not work with Value of type MyEnum can not be assigned to variable of type MyEnum By some experiments I discovered that  inside the lambda does not seem to correspond to MyEnum as defined before.

**EDIT: Solution**

```dart
typedef ButtonChangedCallback<T> = void Function(T value);

class MyWidget<T> extends StatefulWidget {
  ButtonChangedCallback<T>? onCallback;
```

used as

```dart
MyWidget<MyEnum>(
        key: const Key("RadioControls"),
        onCallback: (MyEnum value) =>
          setState(() {
            someSettings.value = value;
          }),
      )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do:

```dart
typedef ButtonChangedCallback = void Function<T>(T value);

class MyWidget<T> extends StatefulWidget {
  ButtonChangedCallback? onCallback;
```

You're declaring that `ButtonChangedCallback` must be a generic function.  Whatever callback is assigned to `MyWidget.onCallback` must itself be generic.  That is, you would only be able to use it as:

```dart
MyWidget(onCallback: <T>(T x) { ... });
```

In the above, `T` is the name of the type *parameter* to your generic, anonymous function.  It is not a type *argument*.  `T` could be named anything, and in your attempt, you happened to name it `MyEnum`, so you ended up in a confusing situation where a generic type parameter had the same name as an actual type.

Additionally, the type parameter for the function would be unrelated to the type parameter for `MyWidget`.

What you probably want is to for the `typedef` to be generic and for the `Function` object to not be:

```dart
typedef ButtonChangedCallback<T> = void Function(T value);

class MyWidget<T> extends StatefulWidget {
  ButtonChangedCallback<T>? onCallback;
```

and now you can use it as:

```dart
MyWidget<MyEnum>(
  onCallback: (value) =>
    setState(() {
      someSettings.value = value;
    }),
```

Answer (score 1):

This way should work:

```
class MyWidget<T> extends StatefulWidget {
  final Function<T>? callback;
  const MyWidget({required this.key, this.callback}) : super(key: key);
}
```

And you instantiate the widget this way:

```
MyWidget<MyEnum>(
  key: const Key("RadioControls"),
  callback: (MyEnum value) {
    setState((){
      someSettings.value = value;
    });
  }
)
```